# How can i track how many times an unity app built for android run on Vuforia engine has opened by user

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have built an AR app in unity which is built for android run on Vuforia. Is there any in which i can check or keep track of how many times the app has opened by user

Comment: It depends on how you use the data afterwards, so your question is incomplete. Are you just looking for [analytics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityAnalytics.html)?

Comment: @artcorpse yes just for analytics.

Comment: Did you have a look at the link provided by artcorpse then?